# What does the term "genType" mean in OpenGL/GLSL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, glsl

In GLSL documentation, the term `genType` is used often as the type of parameters. For example, the function `dot` is documented as follows:

```
float dot(genType x,
          genType y);

double dot(genDType x,
           genDType y);
```

What does the term `genType` mean? What does it abbreviate? Is it used elsewhere than OpenGL?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's a catch-all for multiple types. From the [specification section 8](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf)

> When the built-in functions are specified below, where the input
>   arguments (and corresponding output) can be float , vec2 , vec3 , or
>   vec4 , genType is used as the argument. Where the input arguments (and
>   corresponding output) can be int , ivec2 , ivec3 , or ivec4 , genIType
>   is used as the argument.

For reference, all the "generic" types:

- genType: floats
- genDType: double floats
- genIType: signed integers
- genUType: unsigned integers
- genBType: booleans
- mat: float matrices
- dmat: double matrices

Comment: and short hand for `generic type`

Comment: yeah, though with 5 _different_ "generic types", they're not so generic anymore :p

Comment: Can you really call mat/dmat "generic" types?

Comment: @NicolasLouisGuillemot: that's what the glsl spec says. mat2/mat3/mat4/mat2x3/mat2x4...

Comment: Is there a genType for custom structs? Say I am doing a fragment shader raytracer experiment on shadertoy.com and I have a struct Sphere and a struct Plane and I want to loop through an array with multiple of each of these. Can I?

Comment: for a consortium that's all about API design, Khronos is kinda bad at APIs